# Why is the total item function not printing out the statement

Tags: python, kivy

Why is the 'print(len(val_holder))' in the 'def total_item()' function not working when I run the code. It doesn't print out the statement. When all the three buttons are clicked either in orderly or disorderly manner,  it will store an item in the 'val_holder' and at the end it should print out the total items in the 'val_holder'

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 

val_holder=[]

class LandingScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # put whatever pos_hint value you want.          
        self.btn1=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b1))
        self.btn2=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b2))
        self.btn3=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b3))


            
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.add_widget(self.btn3)

        def click_b1(self, instance):
             val_holder.append('a') 
        def click_b2(self, instance):
             val_holder.append('b')
        def click_b3(self, instance):
             val_holder.append('c') 

        #The function below is not printing out the statement.

        def total_item():
            print(len(val_holder))  
        total_item()

class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Comment: It is running before the UI is even created. See how it is before the `SplashApp().run()` line?

Comment: @Ann Zen I don't understand, okay so where should I place the code and which part of it am I placing

Comment: Perhaps change `return LandingScreen()` to `L = LandingScreen() return L.total_item`.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't see the result of `print(len(val_holder))` statement because when you initialize the `LandingScreen` object, the `val_holder` is still empty. And then when the object has been initialized completely, you click one of three buttons and it'll add item to `val_holder` but because you haven't called `total_item()` function again so you don't see anything. Try below:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 

val_holder=[]

class LandingScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # put whatever pos_hint value you want.          
        self.btn1=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b1))
        self.btn2=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b2))
        self.btn3=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b3))


            
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.add_widget(self.btn3)

        def click_b1(self, instance):
             val_holder.append('a') 
             total_item() # new line
        def click_b2(self, instance):
             val_holder.append('b')
             total_item() # new line
        def click_b3(self, instance):
             val_holder.append('c') 
             total_item() # new line

        #The function below is not printing out the statement.

        def total_item():
            print(len(val_holder))  
       
class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Hope it helps you !!!

Comment: the code print out the total items in the list one after the other when one button is clicked one after the other, but  what do I do if I want to get the total item at once when all the buttons are clicked